# increment column value by 1 based on the previous row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below:

```
data=[['A',1,30],
      ['A',1,2],
      ['A',0,4],
      ['A',1,4],
      ['B',0,5],
      ['B',1,1],
      ['B',0,5],
      ['B',1,8]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['group','var_1','var_2'])
```

I want to create a series of values with index based on below condition:

Step 1) Increment should always happen from 1st row of 'var_2'of each group. For example: for group A, the increment should start from 30 and for group B, increment should start from 5

Step 2) Incremented value where 'var_1" = 1

My desired output:

```
0    30
1    31
3    32
5    6
7    7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) with `groupby` and some tricks on the calculation

```py
df['cumsum'] = df.groupby(['group'])['var_1'].cumsum()
df_first = df.groupby(['group']).agg({'var_1': 'first', 'var_2': 'first'}).reset_index().rename(columns={'var_1': 'first_var_1', 'var_2': 'first_var_2'})
df = df.merge(df_first, on='group')
df['res'] = df['first_var_2'] + df['cumsum'] - df['first_var_1']
res = df[df['var_1'] == 1]['res']

0    30
1    31
3    32
5     6
7     7
Name: res, dtype: int64
```

`df_first` to get the first values on both `var_1` and `var_2` for each group. You need first value of `var_2` as the base value to increment. You also need first value of `var_1` to cancel out the `cumsum` in case first row of `var_1` is 1